# Bash function that checks if string argument is a name of existing (set) or not existing (unset) variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I would like to write a bash  function in Ubuntu 22.04 that works like that

```
Var1=100

is_variable_set "Var1" //Returns 0 (variable exists ie is set)

unset Var1

is_variable_set "Var1" //Returns 1 (variable does not exist ie is not set)
```

My current attempt is not working:

```
is_variable_set()
{
    if [ -z "${1+some_string}" ]
    then
        echo "${1} is unset!"
        return 1
    fi

   return 0
}
```

I tried to used approach from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

But to no avail :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash shell actually provides a built-in test for that. From `help test`:

> ```
> Other operators:
>
>   -o OPTION      True if the shell option OPTION is enabled.
>   -v VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set.
>   -R VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set and is a name
>                  reference.
> ```

So for example

```
$ var=
$ [[ -v var ]] && echo set || echo not set
set
$ 
$ unset var
$ [[ -v var ]] && echo set || echo not set
not set
```

Answer (score 0):

I just googled a bit deeper and I've seen this code:

```
is_variable_set()
{
    local -n refToCheck=$1

    if [ -z "${refToCheck+some_string}" ]
    then
        echo "${1} is unset!"
        return 1
    else
        echo "${1} is SET!"
        return 0
    fi
}
```

It seems to work fine :)